# event.target is always null on Chrome when using HTML input file type and Angular change

Tags: angular, google-chrome, cross-browser

I've implemented a photo upload function to a personal project of mine.

The code is the usual code for handling file uploads using HTML/JavaScript. What I'm basically doing is:

1. Select the file using a `<input type="file" />` element and, on `(change)`, pass the event to an Angular function:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture size="60" #file (change)="savePhoto($event)" />
```

The `input` element is hidden using CSS's `display: none;` setting, so the user just sees the properly styled button.

There is an Angular reference (`#file`), so I can "click" the file input from a properly styled button:

```html
<button mat-menu-item (click)="file.click()">
    <mat-icon>camera</mat-icon>
    <span>Add Photo</span>
</button>
```

2. Inside the function, select the first file under event.target.files (so basically `event.target.files[0]`):

```js
const file = event.target.files[0];
```

3. After getting the file, I could iterate it as I want and proceed the upload (resuming to file.type for simplicity):

```js
const type = file.type;
```

This way, in most browsers, works perfectly. That's not the case on Chrome.

See, when using the exact same code on Chrome, `event.target` is always null, thus `event.target.files` never exists. This is the error I'm getting:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'files')`

Apart from this error, any code that iterates the file variable ends up with this error (as expected, since `event.target` is null and thus `event.target.files` is also undefined):

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
```

With that in mind, I've logged the event ouput to Chrome. This is the `event.target` log under Chrome, see that `target` is null:

```json
{isTrusted: true, type: 'change', target: null, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}
```

This does not happen on Firefox 110.0.1 (macOS), nor Safari (latest, iOS/iPadOS/macOS). I don't know if I'm missing something, or if the event behavior *is different* between browsers.

Tried to apply a timeout, if event.target is not available immediately (although it doesn't do much, actually):

```js
if (event.target === null) {
   setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(event);
      file = event.target.files.item(0);
   }, 0)
} else {
   file = event.target.files[0];
}
```

The output is literally the same:

```json
{isTrusted: true, type: 'change', target: null, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}
```

Also changed the function to check whether `event.target` was null, but to no avail, because on Chrome, event.target for some reason is always null, so the code doesn't even run on this stage.

---

EDIT: Thanks to Markiewic's answer, I was able to finally understand the problem and to solve this issue. I'd like to share a bit more of context, because I did miss some interesting points that led to this bug.

I mistakenly inserted the `input` tag *inside* a `mat-menu` component. What that means is, basically, that the `input` tag is not always available on the element tree. In summary, it is available when the menu is `open`, but gets deleted when the menu is `closed`. This is not an issue under Firefox and Safari (and many other non-Chromium-based browsers), but an issue with Chromium-based browsers (see Markiewic's answer for the appropriate bug filing under Chromium).

The solution I've came to this problem takes the following flow:

1. The `input` element should not be inside the `mat-menu`. With that being said, it can be literally anywhere, except in a place where you don't have the guarantee that the element will be available every time. Thus, I've moved this element to another point in the HTML code, where I'm 100% certain that it'll be available 100% of the time inside the element tree.
2. The styled button still calls the `#file` reference and invokes the `click()` method, so the flow continues as expected.
3. The file is selected by the user.
4. The file is successfully uploaded, since the target is available inside the element tree, thus not being null.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your input is not [present in the element tree](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=857554#c24) by the time the event is fired. This can be repeated on a blank page by creating an input programmatically, setting its type, and calling the click method.

If input is still present in the element tree at this point, but events from it still come with `target = null`, then this is strange. You may have a library installed in your code or a browser extension that affects how events work. Check it in incognito mode on the `about:blank` page. You can also try restarting the Angular server.

In case the source of the problem is not found, I can suggest a workaround: instead of passing the `$event` variable to the `savePhoto` method, pass there `file`. Then you can get all the information you need from it.

```
<input type="file" ... #file (change)="savePhoto(file)" />
```

Comment: Honestly, I haven't thought about passing the file reference to the component function, which would in theory make sense. A thing you've ended up reminding me is that - due to the fact that I'm using a styled button to invoke the `click()` action, the whole input is marked in CSS as `display: none;`, although the element is still present in the DOM anyway, it's just not visible on screen. 

I'll update the thread with this info, try your solution and I'll get back with the results. Thanks!

Comment: I've finally had some time to test out this solution. You were on spot with this Chromium bug! There are a few more things I'd like to clarify, and I'll edit the question to properly explain, but I've marked your answer as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot!